# Determin Depth of Huffman Tree using Input Character pattern (or Frequency)?

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, huffman-code, greedy

I'd like to as a variation on [this question regarding Huffman tree building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28833747/huffman-height-calculation-and-some-challenges). Is there anyway to calculate the depth of a Huffman tree from the input (or frequency), without drawing tree.

if there is no quick way, How the answer of that question was found? Specific Example is : 10-Input Symbol with Frequency 1 to 10 is 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for an equation to take the frequencies and give you the depth, then no, no such equation exists. The proof is that there exist sets of frequencies on which you will have arbitrary choices to make in applying the Huffman algorithm that result in different depth trees! So there isn't even a unique answer to "What is the depth of the Huffman tree?" for some sets of frequencies.

A simple example is the set of frequencies 1, 1, 2, and 2, which can give a depth of 2 or 3 depending on which minimum frequencies are paired when applying the Huffman algorithm.

The only way to get the answer is to apply the Huffman algorithm. You can take some shortcuts to get just the depth, since you won't be using the tree at the end. But you will be effectively building the tree no matter what.

You might be able to *approximate* the depth, or at least put bounds on it, with an entropy equation. In some special cases the bounds may be restrictive enough to give you the exact depth. E.g. if all of the frequencies are equal, then you can calculate the depth to be the ceiling of the log base 2 of the number of symbols.

A cool example that shows that a simple entropy bound won't be strong enough to get the exact answer is when you use the Fibonacci sequence for the frequencies. This assures that the depth of the tree is the number of symbols minus one. So the frequencies 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, and 610 will result in a depth of 14 bits even though the entropy of the lowest frequency symbol is 10.64 bits.

Comment: So How you calculate previous post ? by draw?

Comment: What previous post? What calculation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28833747/huffman-height-calculation-and-some-challenges   / You say the depth is 5. /i think you use a formula or like this..